# How do I flip a function across its center line?

Tags: matlab, function, plot, mirror

Say a defined function begins with point (a,b) and ends with point (c,d). How do I flip this function about its vertical center line (described by x = (c-a)/2)?

Thanks in advance!

```
c = 5.2;
alpha = 0; 

R = [cosd(alpha) sind(alpha) 0; -sind(alpha) cosd(alpha) 0; 0 0 1]; 
l1_vector = [-sqrt(3)*c; 0; 0];
l1_prime = R*l1_vector;

iter = 1;

for i=1:1201
        R = [cosd(alpha) sind(alpha) 0; -sind(alpha) cosd(alpha) 0; 0 0 1]; 
        l1_prime = R*l1_vector; 
        a = l1_prime(1)
        b = l1_prime(2);
        alpha = alpha+.1;
        data1(iter,1:2)=[a,b];
        iter=iter+1;
    end      

a = data1(:,1);
b = data1(:,2);

plot(wrev(a)+a(end)-a(1),b)
axis equal
```

Comment: What have you already tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: In this kind of reflection, I know that the y-coordinates won't change. The x-coordinates can theoretically be calculated by taking every data point to the left of the center line and adding to each horizontal difference between that point and the center line, and doing the same thing for points to the right of the center line but subtracting. For whatever reason, this didn't work for me and gave me the wrong results. It also seems more tedious than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how your function is defined really, but if you have a vector of `x` values and another with corresponding function values `y`, then

```
plot(x,y)
```

plots the function normally, and

```
plot(a,b,2*a(end)-a(1)-cumsum([0;diff(a)]),b)
```

plots the flipped and translated function.

Comment: I gave this a try, but it didn't seem to work. Basically, I have a function that I want to flip and add to the end of my last function. It kind of looks like the McDonald's M. Imagine plotting the left half of the M, then flipping that part about its center line and translating it over to complete the M.

Comment: What about `plot(wrev(x)+(c-a)/2,y)`?

Comment: Yep, I think `wrev(x)+c-a` is what you want though.

Comment: The flipped function begins at the correct position, but the actual function itself is distorted and not an actual mirror of the initial function.

Comment: Can you give an example that shows wrong behaviour? I was testing with `x=0:.1:2` and `y=sin(x)` and `plot(x,y,wrev(x)+x(end)-x(1),y)` seemed to work as you want.

Comment: I should have explained more clearly: I have data points that make up this function, so I am trying to flip the data points.

Comment: I don't follow, I am using data point in vectors `x` and `y`, what is different about your setup? Maybe edit the question with an example of your data is structured.

Comment: It's very strange because I'm doing exactly what you did, David, and I know that yours works, but mine gives the correct beginning and end points but the trend in between is distorted. Please refer back to my initial post. I included my code.

Comment: I edited my answer, it seems to work now. The problem was that the `x` data was not evenly spaced, so the flipped version was distorted.

Comment: You're an angel. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad I could help. If this is a full answer that does what you need, please accept it so that others can see that it has been satisfactorily answered.